# AIR - What version of SQLite is supported

Tags: sqlite, air

What version of SQLite does Air support?

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2842778

Comment: FYI, when creating SQLite databases for use in AIR, create them either using AIR's built-in methods, or if you're creating them outside of AIR, be sure to use "INTEGER" not INT or BIGINT or any other variants of integer that are recognized by SQLite, and this advice is especially important with integer PRIMARY KEY columns. You will get inaccurate results in AIR if you use any of the other variants of int that SQLite supports.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve some clues about AIR's SQLite version by executing this query in your AIR app:

```
SELECT sqlite_source_id();
```

This query returns the date the SQLite database was created plus a SHA1 code. Using what is currently the latest version of AIR – version 3.5.0.600 – the query result is:

```
2010-12-07 20:14:09 a586a4deeb25330037a49df295b36aaf624d0f45
```

Going to [this page at SQLite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) shows the query result above matches SQLite 3.7.4. Note that the version of SQLite used by AIR has been customized by Adobe to support non-standard features such as additional column affinities, including the ability to store and retrieve binary data in AMF3 format.

Comment: Quick forward 7 years and a ~week using Air 32.0: the NEW output now is: `2010-12-07 20:14:09 a586a4deeb25330037a49df295b36aaf624d0f45`

Answer (score 0):

what i know is that air 2 supported 3.6.16 SQLLite version, but that might be little outdated since AIR is at 3.x version :S